# Using ifstream when filename contains wide characters

Tags: c++, windows, unicode, ifstream, c++builder-xe5

Using C++Builder XE5 (bcc32) in Windows 7.

I am trying to open a file whose filename contains a wide character. The actual filename I'm testing with is `C:\bΛx\foo.txt`. The non-ASCII character there is U+039B .

I have this filename stored correctly in a `std::wstring`. However, trying:

```
std::ifstream f( filename.c_str() );
```

fails to open the file.

Of course, in Standard C++ `fopen` only takes `char *`. However, the Dinkumware C++ RTL implementation has an overload accepting `wchar_t *`. Unfortunately the implementation of that overload in `...\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\12.0\source\cpprtl\Source\dinkumware\source\fiopen.cpp` does not call `_wfopen`. Instead it uses `wcstombs` to convert the string to UTF-8 and then calls `fopen`.

Checking the source for `fopen`, it calls the narrow version of an underlying function `___topen` which ultimately passes the UTF-8 string to `CreateFile`.

When I inspect the attempt to open the file using Sysinternals Process Monitor, it shows that it did attempt to open the file with a UTF-8 file string, and the operating system rejected this with the result `NAME COLLISION`.

If I open the file using `_wfopen( filename.c_str(), L"r" )` then all is well and I can read the file using C I/O functions, but I can't use C++ iostreams of course.

Is there any way to use `std::ifstream` to open a file with U+039B or other such characters in the filename?

Note that using `std::wifstream`  doesn't work either (it still tries to open the UTF-8 version of the filename).

Comment: This is clearly a bug in Dinkumware on Windows. Windows does not support UTF-8 in most of its APIs. You should file a report with the Dinkumware authors. Both the `wchar_t*` version of `ifstream`, and `wifstream`, should be using the original value as-is with `_wfopen()`, not converting to UTF-8 and calling `fopen()`. That may work on other platforms, but not on Windows.

Comment: This was reported to Embarcadero 2 years ago, it is still open. See [QC #111462](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=111462).

Comment: @RemyLebeau the Dinkum source has an `#ifdef` setting which would make all calls go via `_wfopen` but (as far as I could see on my quick look) it can't make `fstream(char *)` go to `fopen` and also have `fstream(wchar_t *)` go to `_wfopen` on the same build.  I'm not sure if C++Builder supports having me try to rebuild its packaged version of Dinkum for the `_wfopen` setting?

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks, that report has a quicker short term workaround than buying Josuttis' book (obviously far from ideal tho)

Answer (score 0):

> If I open the file using `_wfopen( filename.c_str(), L"r" )` then all is well and I can read the file using C I/O functions, but I can't use C++ iostreams of course.

I don't see that "of course".  Your problem is reduced to making an iostreams `streambuf` from a `FILE*`.  Howard Hinnant answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19530315/103167) that there's no method provided by the Standard, but implementing a `streambuf`-derived class on top of `FILE*` is pretty straightforward.  He even mentions some code that he feels would be a good starting point.

Note that this only makes sense for a text file.  iostreams and binary files do not get along; there's a character encoding layer and `ios_base::binary` does not turn that off.

Comment: where can I read more about the character encoding layer? (pre C++11)

Comment: Just occurred to me that I could read the whole file into memory via `fread` or similar, and then initialize a `sstream` with the raw data , and cross my fingers

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Definitely worth a shot.